# Why my floating div height is not 100%?

Tags: html, css, height

I want to expand my div height by 100%, but it is not working:

[image]

**So far, my code is:**

```
.add{
border:1px solid #ddd;
display:block;
float:right;
margin:0 0 10px 10px;
padding:10px;
height:100%;
}
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<div>

<div class="add">
<div style="width:100px;height:400px;background:#ccc;"></div>
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... And a lot of text here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... And a lot of text here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... And a lot of text here

</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your html structure also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have specified the height of the outer div.  Something like this will work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.add
{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 10px 10px;
    padding:10px;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 768px;">

<div class="add">
<div style="width:100px;height:400px;background:#ccc;"></div>
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... And a lot of text here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... And a lot of text here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... And a lot of text here

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without specifying height (and not using ugly tables)?

Comment: You can change the style of the outer div to `height: 100%;`, then add another rule `html, body {height: 100%;}` to your CSS.  But either way, the outer div's height MUST BE specified.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CSS 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> **percentage**
>
> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this
>   element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

So, since the containing block has no specified height, the floated element's height is `auto`.

Comment: Certainly not. But the two answers supplied answer your question. Perhaps if you explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish with the layout someone can propose an alternate method. If it's merely the appearance that the column takes up the entire height, the classic [faux column technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) is one way.

Comment: So you propose I change "why is not..." to "how can I do..." so the 2 answers supplied don't answer my question?. Are you the kind of person that if asked "did you cut your hair?" you reply: "no, someone else cut for me"

Comment: You haven't told us exactly what you are trying to accomplish. We can guess, but it'd probably go more quickly if you told us. 2 column layout with 100% height sidebar? If that's what you want, the article I linked to above will accomplish that.

Comment: I did tell what I was trying to accomplish "I want to expand my div height by 100%, but it is not working"